# Autopliot with Whatsapp and route the conversation to Agent in Flex

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

Is there any way to forward the conversation which started with the AutoPilot to a real agent in Flex? For example, somehow, a customer may want to talk to or text with a "Real" agent when they find that the AI bot cannot answer their question. Is that possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The best way to achieve this is to follow this guide on setting up [Handoff from Autopilot to human agents](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/studio#handoff-from-autopilot-to-human-agents).

Briefly, you need to set up an Autopilot task called something like "talk-to-agent". That task should not include a "listen" directive, so that when the task is complete the Autopilot session is over.

Then, you direct incoming messages through a Studio Flow and into the Autopilot bot. When the session ends, you can then check the `CurrentTask` attribute of the Autopilot widget using a Split widget. If the task is equal to "talk-to-agent" you can direct the flow into Flex with the Send to Flex widget.